# most efficient way to redraw control

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, user-controls

I have a custom user control which consists of nothing more than an image of an artificial horizon. I want to move it up and down. When there was part of the main form I was able to constantly update the location using the form.OnPaint method. Now that I've moved the image to a separate class the UserControl.OnPaint method is only called when I do things like move the frame.

What's the best way to update the location of the image with each new value? Right now I'm doing something like this...

```
   public void setPitchAngle(double pitchAngle)
    {
        PitchAngle = pitchAngle;
        this.Invalidate();
        //this.Update();
    }
```

This works but I'm not sure whether or not this is the right way. The call to update doesn't work because its called from a thread other than the creating thread but I know how to fix that if it also needs to be called.

Comment: You need to explain the problem a lot clearer imo. Where is the above code located? By what rule do you want to move the image? The uc_paint __will__ be called whenever you invalidate the uc. Is pitchangle used in the uc_Paint? who calls it?

Comment: In addition, it's unclear what you mean by "best."

Comment: What you have is fine. Until it's not. But if it's not, you need to have a _specific_ problem statement, describing exactly why it's not. The one thing I would change is that IMHO even though the above works, you should use the `Control.Invoke()` method to execute the `Invalidate()` method in the main UI thread. You still won't need `Update()` in that case.

Comment: The above code is a method in the control class. I call it from the form class. I want to move the image to a new XY point.